# How can I make an image go below the text using CSS Media Queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a text and an image overlapping it. What code can I write that makes the image go below the text when A media query is fired.  I tried making that text a block element so that the image goes below but nothing happened.

I also tried making the container's flex-direction column  but that didn't made any change too

[image]

Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="html">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Shivansh</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        
        html {
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }
        /* width */
        
        .homeimgandtextcont {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        
        .homeimg {
            width: 799.557px;
            height: 640px;
            position: relative;
            left: 50%;
        }
        
        .homeheading {
            width: 100px;
            height: 67px;
            position: relative;
            top: 16rem;
            color: black;
            font-family: 'serif';
            font-size: 52px;
            margin-left: 19px;
        }
        
        .hometext {
            position: relative;
            top: -320px;
            color: black;
            font-family: 'serif';
            margin-left: 24px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>


    <section class="sectionhome" id="sectionhome">
        <div class="homecont">

            <div class="homeimgandtextcont">


                <h1 class="homeheading">
                    Sample
                </h1>
                <img class="homeimg" src="https://expo8.netlify.app/logoo.png" alt="Image">
                <p class="hometext">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta culpa vero iure autem provident nobis doloremque, ducimus dolore, dicta praesentium tenetur, sunt eius officia et sit magni iste. Esse, quisquam.
                </p>
            </div>



        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't the image already below the text??

Comment: I want that when the Device gets smaller the image gets below it. see this image https://ibb.co/w4zMZ8k If the Image will get below it this wouldn't happen.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is a a bit confusing. Stuff like    `top: -320px;` should not exist in a ' good written ' css. If you need to do stuff like that you might need to rethink the HTML structure.

Anyway. The easiest way to change the positions of elements is with flexbox.
You can wrap your text and img in a `div` and for desktop use `display:flex; flex-direction:row` and in your media query you can use `flex-direction:column` . So the image will be after( below ) the text.

Check sample below or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97ytjsk0/) and adjust it to your specific needs

```css
div {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

img, p {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  }


@media only screen and (max-width:320px) {
      div {
            flex-direction: column;
      }
      img,p {
          flex: 0 0 100%
          }
}
```

```html
<div class="homeimgandtextcont">
  <p class="hometext">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Soluta culpa vero iure autem provident nobis doloremque, ducimus dolore, dicta praesentium tenetur, sunt eius officia et sit magni iste. Esse, quisquam.
  </p>
  <img class="homeimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Image" />
</div>
```

Comment: The Text is going downwards but I want that the image to go down.  Thanks for helping btw

Comment: @ShivanshArora   Sorry. Use `    flex-direction: column;` insead of column-reverse

Comment: When I used column nothing happens. It remains the same. Thanks

Comment: @ShivanshArora did you check under 320px ? see here https://jsfiddle.net/qna2bcyd/1/

Comment: Ya I checked it

Comment: I didn't include 'flex: 0 0 50%;' Can that be the problem?